# Drawing text in Android Augmented Reality apps using Vuforia SDK

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I'm trying to get my Android AR app working using the Vuforia SDK.

What I would like to do is to draw some text on screen, instead of usual 3D models.

But I cannot find, from the sample apps, where the app actually load such models, and how I could change it.

Anyone can help?

Comment: I found where the object rendering is done (renderFrame method in the native code).

Comment: I used this library : http://fractiousg.blogspot.fr/2012/04/rendering-text-in-opengl-on-android.html You can render text with the font you want !

Comment: @EtienneV how you render the text on vuforia GL surface on camera screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in renderframe in ImageTarget.cpp of Imagetargets vuforia sample,you can comment all gl rendering code to prevent any model rendering then you can draw text on gl surface or simple textview.i have not tried for text but this can be done by as i said.