# Vuforia: How to change teapot with a text in the image targets example?

Tags: vuforia

How do I change the teapot with a text content in Vuforia's Image Target example?

The example is available at : https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps/image-targets-sample-app

Comment: my answer for same in another question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12159133/1206201

Answer (score 3):

I tried to access the links mbrenon gave. Unfortunately they didn't load.

My solution:

The reason why you have a Teapot is because Vuforia is using that class as the image to be shown. In order to have a plane text, I created my own PlaneTextClass.

1. Go to src->main->java->com.qualcomm.vuforia.samples->SampleApplication->utils. There you could find the objects you can use.
2. Add a class named "TextPlane" and extended from "MeshObject"

   ```
   public class TextPlane extends MeshObject {

     private final static double planeVertices[] =
           {
                   -50f, -50f, 0.0f, 50f, -50f, 0.0f, 50f, 50f, 0.0f, -50f, 50f, 0.0f
           };
     private final static double planeTexcoords[] =
           {
                   0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1
           };
     private final static double planeNormals[] =
           {
                   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1
           };
     private final static short planeIndices[] =
           {
                   0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3
           };


     private Buffer mVertBuff;
     private Buffer mTexCoordBuff;
     private Buffer mNormBuff;
     private Buffer mIndBuff;

     public TextPlane(){
       mVertBuff = fillBuffer(planeVertices);
       mTexCoordBuff = fillBuffer(planeTexcoords);
       mNormBuff = fillBuffer(planeNormals);
       mIndBuff = fillBuffer(planeIndices);
     }

     @Override
     public Buffer getBuffer(BUFFER_TYPE bufferType) {
       Buffer result = null;
       switch (bufferType)
       {
           case BUFFER_TYPE_VERTEX:
               result = mVertBuff;
               break;
           case BUFFER_TYPE_TEXTURE_COORD:
               result = mTexCoordBuff;
               break;
           case BUFFER_TYPE_INDICES:
               result = mIndBuff;
               break;
           case BUFFER_TYPE_NORMALS:
               result = mNormBuff;
           default:
               break;
        }
       return result;
     }

     @Override
     public int getNumObjectVertex() {
         return planeVertices.length / 3;
     }

     @Override
     public int getNumObjectIndex() {
         return planeIndices.length;
     }}
   ```

If you want to change the size of the image, change the values in PlaneVertices[].

3. Go to src->main->java->com.qualcomm.vuforia.samples->VuforiaSamples->app->ImageTargets->ImageTargetRenderer.java
4. Add your new class in ImageTargetRenderer.java:

`private TextPlane mTextPlane;`

5. Initilize mTextPlane inside the method initRendering()

`mTextPlane = new TextPlane();`

6. Replace the teapot code with you new textplane code:

Replace this:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                        false, 0, mTeapot.getVertices());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                        false, 0, mTeapot.getNormals());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2,
                        GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mTeapot.getTexCoords());
```

with this:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                        false, 0, mTextPlane.getVertices());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                        false, 0, mTextPlane.getNormals());
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2,
                        GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mTextPlane.getTexCoords());
```

7. Replace this:

`GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,
                            mTeapot.getNumObjectIndex(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                            mTeapot.getIndices());`

With this:

```
GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,
                            mTextPlane.getNumObjectIndex(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                            mTextPlane.getIndices());
```

8. Try it. It should work!

Comment: I used above code but getting black background instead transparent one.

Comment: What about change in loadTextures in ImageTargets.java? Where can we edit the text to the text we want to be seen.Kindly tell me of all changes to be done –

Comment: how to add text to the loadTextures method that is in vector  instead of images .Please help @Fernando Cardenas