# Vuforia: overlaying a texture onto a target instead of the teapot - problems with C++ file location

Tags: vuforia

I'm trying to place a texture over a target in Vuforia (similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939607/vuforia-how-to-change-teapot-with-a-text-in-the-image-targets-example)), but am running into difficulty. I'm using Eclipse Luna, on Ubuntu 14.04.

So far I've done the following:

1. Installed the Vuforia Samples Project (with ImageTarget, Multi-Targets, User-defined targets, etc. in it) - this works find under normal Java environment.
2. Installed Android NDK, & setup directory in preferences.
3. I have added Android NDK support to the Vuforia samples project (via Android Tools menu)
4. I have built all.

Whilst the JNI directory appears, it only contains `VuforiaSamples.cpp`. I can't find `ImageTargets.cpp` as required in [this tutorial](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/textured-plane-target).

Any ideas what I need to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I didn't need to use the NDK. What I wanted to achieve was possible with Java alone.

To achieve this, take a look in the "...SampleApplications.util" package of the Java demo project and duplicate the "CubeObject", calling it something like "MyObject". You can then alter the geometry within this new object class.

To implement your new object class, take a look at the "...Render.java" file. In the rendering method you will see what code to replace with your own code.