# How can I modify the camera view in Vuforia?

Tags: android, camera, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm doing a project using Vuforia AR SDK (for Android) using the front camera and doing ImageTarget recognition.  But the question is, when I flat the book on the desktop, it can not be tracked by Vuforia (see the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrUrt.jpg)).

I know in Android I can use method just like android.graphic.Camera.rotateX to modify the view; can I do it in Vuforia? Or is there some other way to make it better when flat book on the desktop for quicker recognition speed?

Comment: I found the solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939607/vuforia-how-to-change-teapot-with-a-text-in-the-image-targets-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use there [Extended Tracking](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Extended-Tracking) feature. It should help you with tracking, but it is not improving recognition in this kind of conditions like flat book.